# Streamlit cache Keras trained model

Tags: keras, streamlit

I have trained a model (via Keras framework), exported it with `model.save('model.hdf5')` and now I want to integrate it with the awesome Streamlit.
Obviously, I do not want to load the model every time the end-user insert a new input, but to load it once and for all.
so my code looks something like that:

```
@st.cache
def load_my_model():
    model = load_model('model.hdf5')
    model.summary()

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st.title('My first app')
    sentence = st.text_input('Input your sentence here:')
    model = load_my_model()
    if sentence:
        y_hat = model.predict(sentence)
```

In that way I got:

> "streamlit.errors.UnhashableType: "

exception.
I tried to use `@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)` and when I run a query at the streamlit page. I got:

> "TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 80), dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph."

(Of-course without any cache decorators the model is loaded and works fine)

HOW should I properly load **and cache** a Keras trained model?

- Python ver: 2.7 (unfortunately)
- Keras ver: 2.1.3
- Tensorflow ver: 1.3.0
- Streamlit ver: 0.55.2

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

1. adding `_make_predict_function()` call
2. return the session

```
from keras import backend as K

@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def load_model():
    model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
    model._make_predict_function()
    model.summary()  # included to make it visible when model is reloaded
    session = K.get_session()
    return model, session

if __name__ == '__main__':
    st.title('My first app')
    sentence = st.text_input('Input your sentence here:')
    model, session = load_model()
    if sentence:
        K.set_session(session)
        y_hat = model.predict(sentence)
```